# Can't connect my LG laptop with cable between Mini-USB to either net

Tags: networking

I have an LG 17Z990 Laptop with no RG45 but a cable to a  Mini-USB but it does not connect.  wWat is the issue?  Do I need a new driver?

Comment: Try a regular USB port to USB Ethernet.  I have these and they work.

Comment: Which either net?

Comment: They don't have an RG45 connector on this LG laptop.